# How to style placeholder?

Tags: css, reactjs, drop-down-menu

How Can I style the placeholder in the styles.ts file. Not working right now.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TextStyle } from 'react-native';
import DropDownPicker, { ItemType } from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';

import { StyledDropDownPicker, PlaceholderStyle } from './styles';

interface SelectInputProps {
  open?: boolean;
  value?: string | null;
  items?: ItemType<string>[];
}

export default function SelectInput({ open, value }: SelectInputProps) {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState<string | null>(
    value || null
  );
  
  const [openList, setOpenList] = useState<boolean>(open || false);

  const showitems = [
    { label: 'Artes', value: 'artes' },
    { label: 'Biologia', value: 'biologia' },
    { label: 'Espanhol', value: 'espanhol' },
    { label: 'Filosofia', value: 'filosofia' },
    { label: 'Física', value: 'fisica' },
    { label: 'Geografia', value: 'geografia' },
    { label: 'História', value: 'historia' },
    { label: 'Literatura', value: 'literatura' },
    { label: 'Matemática', value: 'matematica' },
    { label: 'Português', value: 'portugues' },
    { label: 'Quimica', value: 'quimica' },
    { label: 'Redação', value: 'redacao' },
    { label: 'Sociologia', value: 'sociologia' },
  ];
    
  const placeholderStyle: TextStyle = PlaceholderStyle as TextStyle;

  return (
    <>
      <StyledDropDownPicker
        open={openList}
        value={selectedValue}
        items={showitems}
        setOpen={() => setOpenList(!openList)}
        setValue={setSelectedValue}
        placeholder="Selecionar matéria:"
        placeholderStyle={placeholderStyle}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import { TextStyle } from 'react-native';
import metrics from '@/utils/theme';
import colors from '@/utils/colors';

import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';

export const StyledDropDownPicker = styled(DropDownPicker)`
  background-color: ${colors.white};
`;

export const PlaceholderStyle = styled(DropDownPicker)`
  color: 'red';
  font-weight: bold;
`;
```

I was expecting the placeholder of the list would be red. No errors in VSCode.

I am working with this library: https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/docs/usage

I can style in the index.ts file. But i need to do in the styles.ts file, and also I need to write using template literal, because of company stadards.

Comment: I have no experience working with the library, but according to the docs ([at this link](https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/docs/advanced/placeholder)) `placeholderStyle` seems to use a JavaScript object ([like React doc explains](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style)), yet I see that you're using StyledComponents for styling. Did you confirm if this Dropdown Picker library supports StyledComponents? Have you tried basic JavaScript object to test out?

Answer (score 0):

Because your question doesn't refer to React, but your code specifically does, I will answer this in two ways.

First, with the React. A simple look at the docs for your "react-native-dropdown-picker" object, shows that it expects the format for its placeholderStyle to be like so..

```
{{
  color: "grey",
  fontWeight: "bold"
}}
```

As can be seen [here](https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/docs/advanced/placeholder). (mods, no archive link is available, so this is direct link)

From your code above, that doesn't look like the format you are supplying, as yours only has 1 level of brackets while theirs has two. ie: *{ key:value }* vs *{{ key:value}}*.

Meanwhile in your import/export you refer to **PlaceholderStyle**, yet further down the code you refer to is as **placeholderStyle**. ie: *PascalCase* vs *camelCase*.

Now, my experience of React is a little bit rusty so you will forgive me if those two suggestions are not relevant to your issue.

My main reason for replying is that you can style placeholder text in native CSS, and do so very easily, with the pseudo-element **::placeholder**. MDN documentation can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20240111175250/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder) (*archived link*), although it can need some browser prefixes based on the type and version you are targetting. This [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20240105175132/https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/) (*archived link*) from css-tricks shows what they are and for which browser.

One final link, and that is the browser support for ::placeholder which can be found on the caniuse website, the link is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230921161805/https://caniuse.com/css-placeholder) (*archived link*).

Comment: Mods, you might also want to link to this question..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-html-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css

..as it is certainly related and if it's specifically about the placeholder, rather than React, then it seems to answer the question OP has asked.